VBA Sort horizontally on current selection
I have to order and sort several workbooks of different column lengths and row amounts. I would like the script to be dynamic in the selection. The starting point will always be the same C1. The script is below and I have included "Selection" and "xlToRight" in the ranges. However, that does not work. I know nothing of VBA and am learning on the fly. Edit: I would like to sort on row 2 so C2 I believe.
 Range("C1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Selection, Selection) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").Sort
        .SetRange Range("C1:xlToRight")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply


Find last row and then find last column and then construct your range. So your range becomes ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,3),ws.Cells(LastRow,LastColumn) where ws is your relevant worksheet. And then sort on this range. THIS can help you find last row and column using .Find

Side note: It's a good idea to avoid using Select in your code
